# C++ Windows Form - If statements

Tags: c++, winforms

I'm trying to make a password strength checker, at the moment i've got it setup so that if 'password' is typed into the password field then the strength goes red, and that if you type anything else it goes green

[image: **enter image description here**]

I've done this using the following if statement:

```
try{

         if (password_textbox_form3->Text == "password")

         {
             strength_color_textbox->BackColor = Color::Red;
         }
         else
         {
             strength_color_textbox->BackColor = Color::Green;
         }
         }
         catch (Exception^ )
         {
             strength_color_textbox->BackColor = Color::Black;
         }
```

What i'm trying to do now and what i'm stuck on, is how to create a field called passwordscore that goes through a list of if statements and adds 10 if for example the password they have entered has more than 8 chars, and then from this score I can change the color of the strength box (red to green) that way

```
String ^ strength = password_textbox_form3->Text; //makes whatever the user enters in pw tb now called string
         int passwordscore=0;

         while // some sort of while loop to increment passwordscore? //passwordscore=passwordscore+1; 

         try{
         if (strength //contains more than 8 characters)
         {
             //passwordscore +10
         }
         if (strength //contains a special character !"£$%^&*)
         {
             //password score +10
         }

         if (passwordscore <=10)
         {
             strength_color_textbox->BackColor = Color::Red;
         }

         if (passwordscore <=20)
         {
             strength_colour_textbox->BackColor = Color::Green;
         }
```

I've started by assigning the contents of the password textbox to a string called strength (i think) and then got stuck on the IF statements such as how to see if strength has more than 8 characters etc

Any help or direction is appreciated, thanks

EDIT - found this from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96e98e93-f7bb-42d2-8451-cafca3c6686c/wpf-password-strength-meter?forum=wpf) but I think it's in C#, can't be that much different to what i'm trying to do?

```
String ^ strength = password_textbox_form3->Text;

        int numberOfDigits = 0;
        int numberOfLetters = 0;
        int numberOfSymbols = 0;
        foreach (char c in strength)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                numberOfDigits++;
            }
            else if (char.IsLetter(c))
            {
                numberOfLetters++;
            }
            else if(char.IsSymbol(c))
            {
                numberOfSymbols++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take in the password as characters, and count the number of characters in the password form so that if the number of characters is >= 8 you can set the strength points to ten. Additionally you can use strings and put individual characters into a vector, and use the vector's index to count the # of characters.

EDIT TO FIRST EDIT:

Just to explain the new code posted:
A character can be either a alphabetical character (a,b,c) a number(1,2,3) or a symbol(+*^)  obviously.

In the code they use one general FOREACH statement to contain three other if statements in which the character is checked to see if it is an alphabetical char a num or a symbol using the std library functions IsDigit IsSymbol IsLetter.

It adds one to the appropriate, initially declared variables whenever a character qualifies as one of the three categories.

For your purpose, you could use a similar technique but declare an int Pw_Str and Total_Char and add an if statement to increase Total_Char as necessary. When Total_Char exceeds 8 you can add 10 to Pw_Str as required and change the color using the Pw_Str variable.

To make any such code more compact instead of using if statements over and over i would suggest using a FOR loop to wind through each character and to add to the necessary variables.